# Tensorflow - Batching variable shape tensors - TFRecord

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow

Hi stackoverflow comunity.

My question/problem is the next. I have a [TfRecord](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/reading_data) file  and i would like to feed it into a model. The entries on the file are lists of int64, of variable size. Something like: 
[ 121 , 122 , 158 ..  ]   [ 10 , 15]
the first one represent the inputs to the RNN network an he second one some targets. But I'd been struggling to create the appropriate pipe line lo read those entires. I think the main reason is because they are diferent in size. 
So far i have the following, Building the queue with string_input_producer and parsing the elements readed:

```
filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(   data_files    )

        _ , encoded_examples = tf.TFRecordReader(
            options = tf.python_io.TFRecordOptions  (
                compression_type= TFRecordCompressionType.GZIP
            )
        ).read_up_to( filename_queue , self.batch_size)



        feature, target =  parse_examples( encoded_examples )
```

and the parse_examples function:

```
def parse_examples( examples ):
    feature_map = {
        'target': tf.VarLenFeature(
            dtype = tf.int64
        ) ,
        'feature': tf.VarLenFeature(
        dtype = tf.int64
        )
    }
    parsed = tf.parse_example(examples , feature_map )
   continue below...
```

then i proceed to manipulate this lists, what i would like to do is, take the target input,read their elements and make a onehot encoding representation, so the output target should have a shape like [ Nmax ]  , [ 0 , 0 .. 1 , 1 , 0] 
and for the features tensor i want each int in the sequence to represent a onehot tensor, in this case the shape of this tensor should be [ Nsamples  , Nmax] with Nsamples the number of elements readed from the record.

So i do the following :

```
sparse_target_indices = tf.reshape( parsed['target'].values , shape=(-1 , ) )
target = tf.one_hot( sparse_target_indices , TOTAL_ITEMS , on_value = 1.0 ,
                         off_value = 0.  )

target = tf.reduce_sum( target , 0   )
target = tf.reshape( target , [ -1 ,TOTAL_ITEMS ] )
```

and with this i presume i have my right input. 
for the features i do something similar.

```
sparse_feature_indices = tf.reshape(  parsed['feature'].indices , shape=(-1 , ) )
features = tf.one_hot( sparse_feature_indices , TOTAL_ITEMS , on_value = 1.0 ,
                           off_value = 0.0 ,  )

features = tf.reshape( features , shape = (-1  ,TOTAL_ITEMS )  )
```

the shape of targets is then [1 , TOTAL_ITEMS ] and as for features [ ? , TOTAL_ITEMS] so i assume I'm in the right track . But the problem comes next, when I try to build a batch with this tensors using

```
#continuation...
result = tf.train.batch(
            [feature,target] , batch_size = self.batch_size  ,
            capacity = capacity ,
            allow_smaller_final_batch=True ,

            enqueue_many = True 
        )
```

Without running the graph, I receive a warning telling :

**tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:993] Invalid argument: Shape mismatch in tuple component 1. Expected [1038,49690], got [1,49690]**  here 49690 is the TOTAL_ITEMS constant

and if I run the operation it obviously doesn't work. I'm still learning about tensorflow and i dont know from where this error really comes. But i believe something in going on in the call [tf.train.batch](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/batch), that doesn't allow me to create the desired batch. So the question is, how can i create my batch of elements, what i need is an each training example to be **[ batch_size , ? , TOTAL_ITEMS]** with their respective targets **[batch_size , TOTAL_ITEMS]** and ? being the number of inputs in the sequence.

Or there is a better approach to do this ? Considering that i would like to read my samples from the TFRecord file.

Thanks in advance, and any help and advice would be greatly appreciated.